# Why serialize an object with JsonPropery attribute works in Debug mode and not in Release?

Tags: android, xamarin, json.net

I'm developing an app with Xamarin for Android
I have an object with several properties each with a JsonProperty attribute this way

```
Public class Tarea
{
    [JsonProperty]
    Public int id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty]
    Public string tarea{get; set;}

}
```

The problem is that when I do this

```
Tarea oTarea = new Tarea();
oTarea.id = 1;
oTarea.tarea = "my homework";
String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (oTarea);
```

Works fine in Debug (from Visual Studio) but when I compile in Release, the json string is null.
I have detected that if I override the ToString property to the object, this way

```
Public class Tarea
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        Public int id {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty]
        Public string tarea {get; set;}

        Public override ToString () {
           Return tarea;
        }
    }
```

When serializing if an object is created only with the assigned *tarea* property, without displaying any further property. Finally I had to serialize another object without the JsonProperty attributes but I would like to know why it works in Debug and not in Release.

Comment: Right Click on your specific project (not Solution) -> Android Options -> Linker -> Choose "None" in Linking. This will include all dlls in the Release Library.